# CSS - Only Horizontal Overflow?

Tags: html, xhtml, overflow, css

Is it possible to achieve only horizontal overflow in CSS 2.1?

```
overflow: auto;
```

Will cause a block element to have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. I want a block element (let's say `<div>`) which will display only horizontal scrollbars. How do I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try `overflow-x: auto;`

It even works in IE6!

Comment: For FF you can use `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;` -- I'm not sure about Webkit.

Comment: Although Mozilla claims that it will work in FF as low as version 1.5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow-x

Answer (score 6):

I tried `overflow-x: hidden;` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
overflow-x: clip;
```

Was what I needed