# Keep top position of dynamically created <ul>

Tags: html, css

I'm creating web app and I'm stuck so I need your help.
So, user can dinamically create `<ul>` which appears in container, everything is ok until number of unordered lists exceeds the width of container, then those lists starts to appear under already created lists, but I want them always on top of container and when user needs more space to store all list horizontal scrollbar should appear. I already placed `overflow: auto;` in my container but it only works for vertical scrollbar.

```
<div class="columns columnsPrivate">
   ... some simple unordered lists with couple list items which I append using javascript

</div
```

So my question is, how to force those unordered lists to appear on top of 'columns' class, and when I say on top I mean `position: relative: top: 0px;`, without placing them below already created lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AyjZf/

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I have unordered lists which represents columns and list items represents rows, so every columns must be next to another columns and list items below list item but inside it's parent. So I achieved that easily but when I add another column it goes below other columns and rows

Comment: Actually it works, it seems I had float:left; that's way it didn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This one's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336600/css-only-horizontal-overflow), be sure to do a little more research next time :)

Use `overflow-x: auto;` for horizontal scrollbars.